# Expand by ID for future periods only

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Is there a way to fill in for implicit missingness for future dates based on id?

For example, imagine a experiment that starts in Jan-2016. I have 3 participants that join in at different periods. Subject 1 joins me in Jan and continues to stay until Aug. Subj 2 joins me in March, and stays in the experiment until August. Subject 3 also joins me in March, but drops out sometime in in May, so no observations are recorded for periods May-Aug.

The question is, how do I fill in the dates when subject 3 dropped out of the experiment? Here is some mock data for how things look like:

```
   Subject   Date
1        1 Jan-16
2        1 Feb-16
3        1 Mar-16
4        1 Apr-16
5        1 May-16
6        1 Jun-16
7        1 Jul-16
8        1 Aug-16
9        2 Mar-16
10       2 Apr-16
11       2 May-16
12       2 Jun-16
13       2 Jul-16
14       2 Aug-16
15       3 Mar-16
16       3 Apr-16




structure(list(Subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Date = structure(c(5L, 4L, 8L, 2L, 
9L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 2L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
"Apr-16", "Aug-16", "Feb-16", "Jan-16", "Jul-16", "Jun-16", "Mar-16", 
"May-16"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), .Names = c("Subject", "Date"))
```

**And here is how the data should look like:**

```
   Subject   Date
1        1 Jan-16
2        1 Feb-16
3        1 Mar-16
4        1 Apr-16
5        1 May-16
6        1 Jun-16
7        1 Jul-16
8        1 Aug-16
9        2 Mar-16
10       2 Apr-16
11       2 May-16
12       2 Jun-16
13       2 Jul-16
14       2 Aug-16
15       3 Mar-16
16       3 Apr-16
17       3 May-16
18       3 Jun-16
19       3 Jul-16
20       3 Aug-16

structure(list(Subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Date = structure(c(4L, 
3L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 8L, 
6L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("Apr-16", "Aug-16", "Feb-16", "Jan-16", 
"Jul-16", "Jun-16", "Mar-16", "May-16"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), .Names = c("Subject", "Date"))
```

I tried using `expand` from `tidyr` and `TimeFill` from `DataCombine` package, but the issue with those approaches is that I would get dates for periods before a participant joined an experiment. In this particular instance, I only want the periods to be filled for cases when a participant drops out of an experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `complete` function from `tidyr` is designed for turning implicit missing values into explicit missing values. We will have to do some filtering to not include past completion. The easiest way seems to be to do a join on a table with starting values:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- df %>% 
  filter(Date != '') %>% 
  droplevels() %>% 
  group_by(Subject)

df2 <- summarise(df, start = first(Date))

df %>%
  complete(Subject, Date) %>%
  left_join(df2) %>% 
  mutate(Date2 = as.Date(paste0('01-', Date), format = '%d-%b-%y'),
         start = as.Date(paste0('01-', start), format = '%d-%b-%y')) %>% 
  filter(Date2 >= start) %>%
  arrange(Subject, Date2) %>% 
  select(-start, -Date2)
```

Result:

```
Source: local data frame [20 x 2]
Groups: Subject [3]

   Subject   Date
     <int> <fctr>
1        1 Jan-16
2        1 Feb-16
3        1 Mar-16
4        1 Apr-16
5        1 May-16
6        1 Jun-16
7        1 Jul-16
8        1 Aug-16
9        2 Mar-16
10       2 Apr-16
11       2 May-16
12       2 Jun-16
13       2 Jul-16
14       2 Aug-16
15       3 Mar-16
16       3 Apr-16
17       3 May-16
18       3 Jun-16
19       3 Jul-16
20       3 Aug-16
```

I use date conversion to do a reliable comparison with the starting date, but you might be able to use the `row_number`s somehow. A problem is that `complete` will rearrange the data.

p.s. Note that your example `dput` has an empty factor level (`""`), so I filter that out first.

Comment: Why use `complete` instead of `expand` though?

Comment: @Aramis7d. if there's any other variables they will be maintained. I figured it was likely OP has some measurements for each subject on the observed dates, and he simply gave a minimal example.

Comment: Agreed. But since OP's concern was regarding the dates before joining date, I figured he was preserving the rest of the columns anyhow. Was just curious if I was missing out on some useful tidyr voodoo. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Axeman for the solution. Yes, I have some other variables and I'm preserving them for the observed dates.